# Ошибка при редиректе на https в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, редирект

При принудительном использовании https в .htaccess, не открывается сайт с ошибкой "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Без него всё работает нормально, в чём проблема?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(login|register|reset-password|faq|change-password|logout|holo|about|my-account|contact|submit|check)?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^details-(.*)?$ index.php?a=details&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^recovery-(.*)?$ index.php?a=recovery&hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^refid=(.*)?$ index.php?refid=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 2):

Помимо файла .htaccess, перенаправления могут происходить из-за внутренних настроек CMS. Поэтому вам так же нужно проверить какие настройки, относящиеся к адресу сайта, указаны в конфигурационных файлах и/или БД вашей CMS.
Кроме того, если вам принудительно нужно выставить https, почему в приведённом вами файле, последнее правило осуществляет перенаправление на http?